# Combining two Jasper reports

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I have a web application with a dropdown from where user could select the type of report viz. report1, report2, report3, etc.

Based on the report selected, a Jasper report is compiled on the server and opens as a pop up in PDF format.

On the server side, I am implementing each report in a separate method using below code say for e.g. for report1:

```java
JRBeanCollectionDataSource report1DataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(resultSetBeanListReport1);

InputStream inputStreamReport1 = new FileInputStream(request.getSession().getServletContext ().getRealPath(jrxmlFilePath + "report1.jrxml"));

JasperDesign jasperDesignReport1 = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStreamReport1);

JasperReport jasperReportReport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignReport1);

bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReportReport1, titleMapReport1,   report1DataSource);
```

Similarly, report2 is in a separate method with below code:

```java
JRBeanCollectionDataSource invstSummDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(resultSetBeanListInvstOfSumm);

InputStream inputStreamInvstSumm = new FileInputStream(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(jrxmlFilePath + "investSummary.jrxml"));

JasperDesign jasperDesignInvstSumm = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStreamInvstSumm);

JasperReport jasperReportInvstSumm = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignInvstSumm);

bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReportInvstSumm, titleMapInvstSumm, invstSummDataSource);
```

Now I have a requirement that if report1 is selected from the dropdown, the resulting PDF should contain all the reports one after other in the same PDF.

How can I combine above two lines of codes to finally generate a single PDF?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is sample code for combining multiple jasper prints

```
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
// Your code to get Jasperreport objects
JasperReport jasperReportReport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignReport1);
jasperPrints.add(jasperReportReport1);
JasperReport jasperReportReport2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignReport2);
jasperPrints.add(jasperReportReport2);
JasperReport jasperReportReport3 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignReport3);
jasperPrints.add(jasperReportReport3);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
//Create new FileOutputStream or you can use Http Servlet Response.getOutputStream() to get Servlet output stream
// Or if you want bytes create ByteArrayOutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
exporter.exportReport();
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 17):

This answer is to help user using latest version of Jasper-Report. In
[@Sangram Jadhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990359/sangram-jadhav) accept answer the
[`JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JASPER_PRINT_LIST) is **deprecated**

The **current code** would be:

```
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report1, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint1);
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint2);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList)); //Set as export input my list with JasperPrint s
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/output.pdf")); //or any other out streaam
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true); //add this so your bookmarks work, you may set other parameters
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Is there any chance to recalculate the page numbers? I tried it and every report starts with page number 1.

Comment: @dur I posted a Q/A on this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426311/)

Answer (score 2):

You can either merge reports before generating PDFs using `JasperPrint` or after generating PDFs using iText.

For the `JasperPrint` solution: you will generate the 2 (or more) `JasperPrint`s then get the content pages and concat them.

```java
JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url.openStream(), parameters,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(inspBean));
JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url.openStream(), parameters,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(inspBean));

List pages = jp2 .getPages();
for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
    JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
    jp1.addPage(object);
}
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp1,false);
```

For the iText solution after generating the PDFs:

```java
void concatPDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles, OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {

    Document document = new Document();
    try {
      List<InputStream> pdfs = streamOfPDFFiles;
      List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
      int totalPages = 0;
      Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

      // Create Readers for the pdfs.
      while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
        InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        readers.add(pdfReader);
        totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
      }
      // Create a writer for the outputstream
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

      document.open();
      BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
      // data

      PdfImportedPage page;
      int currentPageNumber = 0;
      int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
      Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

      // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
      while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

        // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
        while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
          document.newPage();
          pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
          currentPageNumber++;
          page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
          cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

          // Code for pagination.
          if (paginate) {
            cb.beginText();
            cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "" + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520, 5, 0);
            cb.endText();
          }
        }
        pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
      }
      outputStream.flush();
      document.close();
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (document.isOpen())
        document.close();
      try {
        if (outputStream != null)
          outputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf returns a byte array which I am returning from my method. Is there a way to convert list of JRPrint pages into byte array ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code which i use on grails code .Its gives me two different report in one pdf.

```
String reportDir = Util.getReportDirectory() // my report directory
Map reportParams = new LinkedHashMap()
Map reportParams1 = new LinkedHashMap()

String outputReportName="Test_Output_copy"

reportParams.put('parameter name',"parameter")
reportParams1.put('copy',"Customer's Copy")

JasperReportDef reportDef1 = new JasperReportDef(name: 'testBillReport.jasper', fileFormat: JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT,
            parameters: reportParams, folder: reportDir)
JasperReportDef reportDef2 = new JasperReportDef(name: 'testBillReport.jasper', fileFormat: JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT,
            parameters: reportParams1, folder: reportDir)

List<JasperReportDef> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperReportDef>();
    jasperPrintList.add(reportDef1);
    jasperPrintList.add(reportDef2);

ByteArrayOutputStream report1 = jasperService.generateReport(jasperPrintList);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename="+outputReportName+'.pdf')
    response.contentType = "application/pdf"
    response.outputStream << report1.toByteArray()
```

Comment: What is `jasperService.generateReport`?  It seems like that is a critical piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one this is work for me

```
JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile1,reportParams,Connection);  
JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile2,reportParams,Connection);  
for (int j = 0; j < jp1.getPages().size(); j++) {  
    //Add First report to second report
    jp2.addPage((JRPrintPage) jp1.getPages().get(j));  
}
```