# How to merge two jrxml jasper report into 1 pdf same page

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I tried answer from this site to merge two jrxml jasper into 1 pdf file. Created file contain two page...

How to merge two jrxml into one page?

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/coba.jasper"), param, new JREmptyDataSource());
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/coba2.jasper"), param2, new JREmptyDataSource());

            List pages = jasperPrint2.getPages();
            for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
                JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(i);
                jasperPrint1.addPage(object);
            }                                   
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasper);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\demo.pdf"));
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
            exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is since you are adding a page `addPage`, you need to add the **elements** on a page to another page.

```
JRPrintPage page1 = jasperPrint1.getPages().get(0);
List<JRPrintPage> pages2 = jasperPrint2.getPages();
for (JRPrintPage page : pages2) {
   List<JRPrintElement> elements = page.getElements();
   for (JRPrintElement element : elements) {
     page1.addElement(element);
   }
}
```

This code will add all elements of `jasperPrint2` (in all its pages) in page 1 on `jasperPrint1`

NOTE: Error handling (`Nullpointer`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`) is beyond the scope of the example.

Comment: Thanks Petter... I tried your solution and it works...

But the element overlap...So i must try to get last position of element in page 1 before adding element to that page...

I will try to do that...Thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using **parts** to compose the reports. I'm unsure what advantages or disadvantages this brings though. Maybe that would solve some of the page-number issues.

A report either renders a bunch of bands or parts (pick one):

- **Bands** fill up the pages according to their split style.
- **Parts** each consist of a defined number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: An additional variant is to fill the pdf exporter with multiple `JasperPrint` objects, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24117554/647213. That would be a very late merging and thus probably wouldn't solve the pagenumber-issue though (AFAIK).