# How to merge multiple report into one pdf with no overlap and new page created automatically

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I merge two jasper report into one pdf using "addElement" method.
I used the method explained here [How to merge two jrxml jasper report into 1 pdf same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353244/how-to-merge-two-jrxml-jasper-report-into-1-pdf-same-page/44061249#44061249) to merge multiple reports:

```
JRPrintPage page1 = jasperPrint1.getPages().get(0);
List<JRPrintPage> pages2 = jasperPrint2.getPages();
for (JRPrintPage page : pages2) {
   List<JRPrintElement> elements = page.getElements();
   for (JRPrintElement element : elements) {
     page1.addElement(element);
   }
}
```

Problem 1: I still have overlapping problems in pages. The elements of the second report (jasperPrint2) overlap the last elements of the first report.

Problem 2: jasper do not add page automatically when I use page1.addElement(element), there are elements of the second report not visible.

How can I produce one single pdf correctly concatenating two jasper report?

Comment: You’re adding all the elements of all the pages of the second report to this single first page if the first report. Logically, that will cause the problems that you describe above

Comment: I tried to use addPage instead of addElement, the second report goes in a new page. I'd like to append the second jasper exacly after the end of the first (without blank space to fill the page).  
Into the for loop I used jasperPrint1.addPage(page) without obtaining the desiderd result.

Comment: Another possibility is to merge two separately generated PDF documents. This is possible if page numbers aren't necessary. (It's still possible to add page numbers afterwards, but is more difficult.) See: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/merging-documents-bookmarks

Comment: Thanks Erwin, Thanks Dave. I finally resolved with another approach... using one generic report with subreport inside.