# Java merge two Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I have created two report jrxml with jasper report. In my java program I merge the two report into one PDF with iText.
The problem is that the pdf contains only one report plus a blank page. 
I have also done this proof:
in my java program creation report one creation report two, merge and I see pdf containig only report one plus blank page
in my java program creation report two and then creation report one, merge and I see pdf containing only report two plus blank page

I have to obtain the pdf with both reports
Does someone help me to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Attach the code of my java program:

```
@Name("pdfFactory")
public class PdfScalareFactory {

    private static final String JASPER_FILE_MOVIMENTI = "scalarePdf/pdf_movimenti.jrxml";
    private static final String JASPER_FILE_SCALARE = "scalarePdf/pdf_scalare.jrxml";

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public byte[] rawPdf(BeScalare beScalare, String codTabulato, String output) throws JRException, IOException {

        JRBeanArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(new Object[]{beScalare}); 

        //report's list
        List<byte[]> pdfFilesAsByteArray = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

        //Report one
        Class cScalare = this.getClass();
        ClassLoader clScalare = cScalare.getClassLoader();
        InputStream isScalare = clScalare.getResourceAsStream(JASPER_FILE_SCALARE);
        JasperDesign jasDesignScalare = JRXmlLoader.load(isScalare);
        //compile report one
        JasperReport reportScalare = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasDesignScalare);      
        //parameters report one
        Map<String, Object> paramScalare = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsScalareSaldiPerValuta = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beScalare.getLstBeScalareSaldiPerValuta());
        paramScalare.put("scalareSaldiPerValuta", itemsScalareSaldiPerValuta);
        //fill report one
        JasperPrint jasperPrintScalare = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportScalare, paramScalare, dataSource);
        pdfFilesAsByteArray.add(JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrintScalare));

        //Report two
        Class c = this.getClass();
        ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
        InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream(JASPER_FILE_MOVIMENTI);
        JasperDesign jasDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(is);
        //compile report two
        JasperReport reportMovimenti = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasDesign);
        //parameters report two
        Map<String, Object> paramMovimenti = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        BufferedImage imgNumeroVerde = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/scalarePdf/headphones.png"));
        paramMovimenti.put("numeroVerde", imgNumeroVerde);
        BufferedImage imgInternet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/scalarePdf/internet.png"));
        paramMovimenti.put("internet", imgInternet);        
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsScalareMovimenti = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beScalare.getLstBeScalareMovimenti());
        paramMovimenti.put("scalareMovimenti", itemsScalareMovimenti);
        //fill report two
        JasperPrint jasperPrintMovimenti = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportMovimenti, paramMovimenti, dataSource);
        pdfFilesAsByteArray.add(JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrintMovimenti));

        //merge the two reports in one
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        for (byte[] pdfByteArray : pdfFilesAsByteArray) {

            try {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfByteArray);
                int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

                if (document == null) {
                    document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                    writer = new PdfCopy(document, outStream); // new
                    document.open();
                }
                PdfImportedPage page;
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages;) {
                    ++i;
                    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                    writer.addPage(page);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        document.close();
        outStream.close();
        return outStream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two Jasper reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115885/combining-two-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the data source and not in merging. You create one data source for both reports but the first report will consume it and then the second report has data source with pointer at the end.

You use `JRBeanArrayDataSource` which implements `JRRewindableDataSource` so you can call the `moveFirst()` method to return data source pointer on the first position:

```
//Report two
dataSource.moveFirst();
```

Or you can create the data source again for the second report:

```
//Report two
dataSource = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(new Object[]{beScalare});
```

**Note:** But as *Amongalen* mentioned in the comment it is easier to merge two and more Jasper reports using `JRPdfExporter` and `List<JasperPrint>` instance as an input.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is what I was looking for

Comment: Super, I'm glad it helped to you. Then if you can please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Hi cgrim I've tried to accept your answer by clicking the link but I'm not sure you received it. Could you verify?

Comment: Hi, the answer still looks as unmarked. There is a gray check mark under the down arrow beside the answer and when you click on it the check mark will become green.