# Two different jasper report views in one view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc. I want that when I click on submit button after entering input fields, then two different jasper report will generate in one view(browser tab) or two view also as u know well.

Using below code, when i submit form then only one report is displaying from two report. I want to display two diff. report(pdf) in one view or two as u now well. Please see the problem.

```
My controller is like :

Session session = null;
            Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> parameterMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
            view.setUrl("classpath:/jReport/stock_issuance_toDepartment.jrxml");
            view.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            JasperReportsPdfView view1 = new JasperReportsPdfView();
            view1.setUrl("classpath:/jReport/requirement_order.jrxml");
            view1.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            String hql = "FROM Stock_issuance_toDepartment";
            String hql1 = "FROM Order_Type_Entity";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            Query query1 = session.createQuery(hql1);
            List list = query.list();
            List list1 = query1.list();
JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
                    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);
                    JRDataSource JRdataSource1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list1);
                    parameterMap1.put("datasource", JRdataSource1);
                    mav = new ModelAndView(view, parameterMap);
                    mav = new ModelAndView(view1, parameterMap1);
                    return mav;
```

My expected result is like : two different report will generate (eg: view and view1) and display in one view (in browser tab) or two view as u know better. Thanks in advance.
[image: Report1]
[image: Report2]

Comment: How your report look like? (you can attached a picture of your report)

Comment: ok i'm attaching

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24117554/4423636 this link has e great explanation how to combine two different jasper into one.

Comment: generate the single pdf file then set it to the view

Comment: what i want generate two diff pdf and one how can this possible?